# Is there a name for this metric on a Borel sets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, terminology, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$.
Consider the function $d:\Sigma \times \Sigma \to [0,1]$ given by
$$d(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) = \mu \left\{ (\sigma_1^c \cap \sigma_2) \cup (\sigma_1 \cap \sigma^c_2) \right\}.$$  One can verify that $d$ is a pseudometric (where $d(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) = 0$ means that $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ differ by a set of measure zero).  Does $d$ have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book [Dictionary of distances](https://books.google.com/books?id=I-PQH8gcOjUC&lpg=PA25&ots=5bY662ttFI&dq=counting%20symmetric%20difference%20metric&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=counting%20symmetric%20difference%20metric&f=false) by Deza and Deza lists several names for this object (and its induce metric on the quotient when we identify two sets that differ by measure zero).

- Symmetric difference (pseudo)metric
- Frechet-Nikodym-Aronszayn distance
- Measure metric

---

Google also tells me that [Dave Renfro has a post on Sci.Math](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.math/xR-j_nLoFQE/7n1xXggU4OwJ) which includes a mini survey of some of the research problems where this metric comes into play.

Comment: It is also the distance between the characteristic or indicator functions of the two sets in the Banach space $L^1(\mu)$.

Comment: As a matter of historical interest, Saks used this space to prove what became known as the Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem on the limit of sequences of measures by applying Baire's category theorem to it as a closed subset of a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\sigma_1^c \cap \sigma_2) \cup (\sigma_1 \cap \sigma^c_2)$ is simply the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the sets $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ (also denoted more concisely as $\sigma_1 \triangle \sigma_2$), your metric is often called the **symmetric difference (pseudo)metric** induced by the measure $\mu$.